# Loop through time series data and collect specific timeframe window keeping the runtime O(N)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, runtime

I am trying to loop through a time series data frame and for a specific time, I need to then go back 5 minutes and 10 minutes (need to make sure I also DO NOT over count the data because of multicollinearity) and check if a condition is met. Below is the code that I wrote, I would love for it to be in O(N) and not have to make two loops. I was thinking of saving the index somehow to save space but need help here.

Thanks in advance

Sorry this is not a great question

Comment: Hello Andre, you should try to use iterrows : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html While it doesn't solve the whole issue, this should simplify your code greatly, making it easier to work with.

Comment: @FlorianFasmeyer Thanks! I could but I still would have the O(N^2) issue. The iterate rows method I dont think solves that

Comment: "ERROR 'fillData' is not defined" I think you should try to make your minimal-reproducible-example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) work, especially for algorithms, it helps people help you. And simplify your code if you can. I see many easy improvements.

Comment: @FlorianFasmeyer Yes, the dataframe is defined somewhere else. Just consider it as any timeseries dataframe with a timeframe in nanoseconds precision with some datavalues attributed to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want:

```
fillData.set_index('time', drop=True, inplace=True)
condition = fillData.fill.eq(1)
fillData['500 milli'] = (condition.rolling(pd.Timedelta('500ms'))
                                  .agg(any)
                                  .astype(int))
fillData['6 minutes'] = (condition.rolling(pd.Timedelta('6m'))
                                  .agg(any)
                                  .astype(int))
fillData['6 minutes'][fillData['500 milli'].eq(1)] = 0
fillData.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
```

I'm not sure how `fillData` is sorted. My assumption is that the sorting is ascending (in time). Otherwise you have to reverse it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. This will then look back by 500ms and 6m to check if the fill = 1 and if it is at that index it will mark as 1. is this correct?

Comment: @AndreHaddad That's the idea. And afterwards the `6 minutes` column gets set to 0 whenever the `500 milli` column is 1. I'm not sure though, if that's exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what's going on in your code, but I believe it could be replaced with a single forward pass. Assuming your data is sorted.

```
last_short = filldata['time'][0] - np.timedelta64(9,'ms')
last_long = filldata['time'][0] - np.timedelta64(9,'ms')
for row in fillData.itertuples():
   if row.fill == 1:
      last_short = row.time + np.timedelta64(250,'ms')
      last_long  = row.time + np.timedelta64(3, 'm')
      #filldata['250 mili'][row.Index] = 1 #you might want this line 
   else:
      if row.time <= last_short:
          filldata['250 mili'][row.Index] = 1
      elif row.time <= last_long:#if\elif  your choice
          filldata['6 min'][row.Index] = 1
```

Or you could probably use the `rolling` method of the dataframe.

Comment: For a given timeframe, I am going back 500 milliseconds and 6 minutes (being careful not to double count) and then checking to see if another column ('fill') is equal to 1. if it is then i assign that current timeframe to 1. does that make sense?

Comment: What is the difference from the answer?

Comment: You are calculating the time ahead in your answer and not checking the time in the past. Also let me just note that I really appreciate your input. You actually took time to understand the question while other users just ignored.

Comment: `For each row A if any row B within a given interval before A satisfies a condition then mark A`  is equivalent to `if the row B satisfies condition then all the rows A within a given interval after the B should be marked`.

Comment: I understand it is correct. But the issue here is the following:
If you have an order being filled then you check 250 miliseconds in the past to see if thwere is any order filled. if there is then you set current index to 1 for 250mili column. if there is not then check for 3 minutes, if there is for 3 minutes set index to 1 for 3 min column and so on

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is what "if\elif" comment in the code is about. If I don't understand correctly, you really need to add a minimal-reproducible example to the question.